# usage of "constitute" and "thankful"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> A senior researcher has single-handed[ly] constituted one of the most comprehensive collections of field recordings.

I have three questions,  two pertaining to usage and one to grammar:

1. Should *single-handed* be an adverb describing *constituted*?

2. Can the verb *constitute* be a transitive as well as a causative verb as in the above example? I think that in the above example the word *constitute* is misused to mean *form, establish* or *create.* A researcher does not constitute part of the collection.

When acknowledging thanks for financial support:

> We are thankful to the Smith Foundation for supporting our new research project.

3. According to dictionary meanings, *thankful* does have the meaning of gratitude and appreciations, but with the nuance of relief as in the example, "We are thankful that the storm did not cause more damage." Is my feeling correct?

Comment: (3) Google has this for the pragmatic-marker incarnation of the -ly form: **thankfully**: used to express pleasure or relief at the situation or outcome that one is reporting; fortunately.
"thankfully, everything went smoothly".>> This probably adds the 'relief' connotation to the adjective.

Comment: You should only ask one question at a time. I would suggest that you edit the _thankful_ question out and ask it as a separate question (or just edit it out and use _grateful_ instead).

Comment: (1) Though 'single-handed' can be used as an adverb, I believe its use here at best borders on the ungrammatical; the -ly form is required before the verb. (2) constituted = 'put together; compiled' sounds wrong to me. One can't rule it in or out from the dictionaries I've checked, as they give say 'compose', but I believe they should say " 'compose' meaning 'together constitute', rather than as in 'compose a piece of music' ".

Answer (score 1):

The verb *constitute* is a poor choice there as suggesting that the senior researcher is himself or herself a constituent part of the collection:

> To make up, form, compose; to be the elements or material of which the thing spoken of consists. [OED sense 8]

Better choices for the verb would be *put together* or *assembled.*

And yes, to specify the single-handed manner in which the action of the verb was done, *single-handedly* would be preferable. Alternatively one could make *single-handed* modify the subject or doer, as in “He, single-handed, did it” or  “He did it single-handed.” (The latter may arguably exemplify adverbial use without the *-ly,* but the form with *-ly* works better if it directly precedes the verb, without intervening punctuation.)

Regarding *thankful,* OED defines current usages as wholly synonymous with *grateful,* and gives no hint of the connotation of relief (for evil averted) that you mention. My own sense of the difference between the two is that *thankful* is strongly associated with gratitude towards the deity. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thankful) suggests that to be thankful is simply to be glad, a feeling not particularly directed *to* anyone. In any case, though, *grateful* is the more usual and probably better choice for the context you describe and show, where the feeling is explicitly said to be felt *to* or toward one or more human beings or a human institution.